# Creating a List of Database Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a list based off the query that gets passed into my Method. My issue is determining how to add those items to a list that I return as a result list. The following is the code that includes my list and what will hopefully be the way I populate that list...

```
public void QueryInto<T>(ref List<T> returnType, string queryString, string[] parameters = null)
{    
    try
    {
        // Setup the query.
        SetupCommand(queryString);

        // Setup the parameters.
        AddParameters(parameters);

        // Execute the reader.
        OpenReader();


        // Make sure the statement returns rows...
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // For each row, do this...
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // TODO: use datamapping to map to model and add items to list... 

            }

        }

    }
```

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this, but so far this is the direction Google Has directed me!

Comment: reader.HasRows is not nessecary, if nothing else than the while loop happens insider the if-block, because if it has no rows, the code will never get inside the while loop

Comment: Have you checked `dynamic linq`?

Comment: You could use `Dapper` to execute the sql against your db and return a strongly typed collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) for this.

example useage;

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }
}            

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```